# Python : TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7

When i run my python code through terminal m getting this error :

```
def GPlag(text,encode=False):
        import urllib, urllib2, json

        if encode == True:
            text = text.encode('utf-8')

        query = urllib.quote_plus(text)
        base_url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='
        url = base_url + '%22' + query + '%22'
        request = urllib2.Request(url,None)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        result = json.load(response)
        output = []

        if result['responseData']['results'] != []:
            firstMatch = result['responseData']['results'][0]
            output.append(firstMatch['title'])
            output.append(firstMatch['visibleUrl'])
            output.append(firstMatch['content'])

        return output

        def callGPlag(n):
            for s in n:
                outcome = GPlag(s,encode=True)
```

It gives;

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

in this `if result['responseData']['results']` line. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 ... in <module> GPlagFile(sys.argv[1]) 
 ... in GPlagFile outcome = GPlag(s,encode=True) 
 ... in GPlag if 'results' in result['responseData']: 
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Check it's length instead and/or if `'results'` is in `result['responseData']`.

Comment: @Allendar can you tell me why i am getting this error ?
and how to find the length of it ?

Comment: `if 'result' in result['responseData']:` and another check inside it `if len(result['responseData']['result']) > 0`. Or something similar. The problem you have now is there is nothing there, hence the `NoneType`.

Comment: @Wooble : if i print result['responseData'] no error but when i print result['responseData']['results'] it prints for some as it is in loop and then gives error and loop breaks.

Comment: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` happens because you are trying to access an attribute on `None`.  You are making an incorrect assumption somewhere.  Which line number does the error occur?

Comment: How is this any different from your [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084662/how-to-access-dictionary-values-in-python) question?

Comment: @Allendar : i did what you send and it gave me this Error 

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\wamp\PYTHON\Scripts\test.py", line 73, in <module>
    GPlagFile(sys.argv[1])
  File "c:\wamp\PYTHON\Scripts\test.py", line 67, in GPlagFile
    outcome = GPlag(s,encode=True)
  File "c:\wamp\PYTHON\Scripts\test.py", line 47, in GPlag
    if 'results' in result['responseData']:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable**

Comment: Then there are probably cases too when `responseData` does not exist either inside `result`.

Comment: @Wooble : I dint Lie About Code any time, i just dint post it : instead i posted the result , and when i stopped getting that error i got this error, its obvious that i dont had to post my code for that error.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the line :

```
if result['responseData']['results'] != []:
```

By

```
if ( len(result) and
    'responseData' in result and 
    'results' in result['responseData'] and      
    result['responseData']['results'] != []):
```

Comment: i got this error after replacing it 
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\wamp\PYTHON\Scripts\test.py", line 74, in <module>
    GPlagFile(sys.argv[1])
  File "c:\wamp\PYTHON\Scripts\test.py", line 68, in GPlagFile
    outcome = GPlag(s,encode=True)
  File "c:\wamp\PYTHON\Scripts\test.py", line 50, in GPlag
    if ('responseData' in result and 'results' in result['responseData'] and  re
sult['responseData']['results'] != []):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable**

Comment: This means result is not a dict and that `json.load(response)` returns `None`. I've edited the response to add another test to avoid this error.